# Unable to run ''aws configure'' command on ec2 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am using aws ec2 linux based server,
when i run the command **"aws configure"**

its giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 31, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
ImportError: No module named docs.docstring
```

using the following versions:
python:    3.5
pip:       20.3.4
awscli:    1.18.223
boto3:     1.16.63

Comment: DONT USE AWS CONFIGURE ON EC2 for storing your credentials., posted a solution which tells the way to use roles which is the best practice to run commands on ec2 instance without configuring credentials

Comment: did my solution worked for you? if it did would you accet it as solution so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ITS A VERY BAD PRACTICE TO CONFIGURE YOUR CREDENTIALS ON EC2 instance.
your entire aws account security is at risk**

instead, [use roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) do this if you want to run aws cli commands from ec2 instance. lets say you wan to run aws s3 ls  ( for listing buckets)

- Go to IAM -> roles -> create a role -> select service Ec2.
- attach permissions -> S3 read only access.
- enter description and name of the role
- go to your instance -> right click instance settings
- attach Iam role, you just created
- ssh into your instance.
- run aws configure -> `just hit enter for key id and access key leave it BLANK.`
- enter your region for eg `eu-west-3` so that request got to that region.
- run aws s3 ls

you can see your buckets in the region you mentioned.